# How do I hide unnecessary .directories in my home directory?

Tags: nautilus, files, hidden-files

I found some .files in my home directory now. They are .local, .mozilla, .java, .Skype, .adobe and many more. They make my home directory messy. How to hide these files? They were not present before.

Comment: I meant, you just need to press `Ctrl`+`h` to hide or unhide files. Be aware that most of this files/directories store important configurations, don't delete them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Dot-files" are normally hidden when you request a listing of a directory.  This is true for both GUI and CLI.  You've toggled "Show/Hide Hidden Files" to show the files and directories and need to toggle to hide them.

Many Linux [GUI File Managers/Browsers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_manager) have this set to the keyboard shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> .  You can press this combination to toggle to show/hide hidden files and directories.

Similarly, the `ls` command in a BASH terminal has the `-a` flag, which shows **all** files, without skipping these dot-files: `ls -a`.